# ubuntu 20.04 laptop turns snow screen

Tags: 20.04, display, suspend, screen

My laptop is MECHREV Code-01, with AMD 4800H and 32GB memory.
Recently the laptop shows snow screen after the following events:

1. wake from sleep;
2. screen goes dark;
3. switch to TTY1 (using alt+ctrl+f1). Note that switching to other terminals work fine.

The issue occurs about one month ago. I reverted to previous backup image and the issue seems gone. Then it came back sometime later (probably triggered by automated update).
The laptop gets updates from official ubuntu software repos.

I'm glad to provide any other information necessary.

Comment: Try to restart your laptop. It might fix your snow screen laptop problem. If that does not fix it try to connect a mointer and see if the snow thing still comes. If it does not its something to do with your laptop screen

Comment: Restarting the computer doesn't solve it. If the computer goes idle the problem shows up again. I haven't tried connecting to a monitor, but I need to use the laptop where there's no external monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the latest kernel: 5.13.0-39-generic
I don't know what it is, but switching to an older kernel fixed the problem.

I tried several kernels. Some old kernel doesn't have touchpad support or doesn't recognize the built-in GPU model.

The kernel works fine for me is 5.13.0-28-generic.